# Cannot implicitly convert type 'PostgreSql.Entities.UserActionEntity' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<PostgreSql.Entities.UserActionEntity>

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to return a UserActionEntity from my DB and it is giving me the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'PostgreSql.Entities.UserActionEntity' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<PostgreSql.Entities.UserActionEntity>'
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
    public Task<UserActionEntity> GetUserActionStatus()
        {
            var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            var result = _context.tbl_UserActions
                    .Where(x => x.UserId.ToString() == userId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

            return result;
}
```

Why am I getting the error when returning result? Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `Task.FromResult(result)` instead. Your method signature expects to return `Task<UserActionEntity>`, so since the `result` is a UserActionEntity, wrap it into a `Task` with [Task.FromResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, you can think why your `_context` can't return data asynchronously. Your method expects this action return a Task. Of course `Task.FromResult` will work here